# How do I enable setting tab colors on iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

Using iTerm2, I notice my peers have an option to right-click the menu and select a color for it. I don't have that option, and right-clicking only gives me the options to 'Select', 'Close Tab', and 'Move to new window'.

[image]

Couldn't find any reference online as to how to enable this option. I do have colors inside the terminal and can set the tab color programatically, but not manually. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your preferences are corrupted. Try this:

1. Quit iTerm2 if it's running.
2. Rename the preference file ~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.iTerm.plist to ~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.iTerm.plist.bak
3. Start iTerm2, create some tabs and see if the context menu now has the Tab Color: options.

The plist file is stored in binary format, but can be output as XML text with the /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy tool (/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy --help for options). You could probably compare the new and old ones to determine what may be set incorrectly.

Note: the Tab Color: option should also be available from iTerm2's View menu.

Comment: I don't have that file at all. Which made me think maybe something is really messed up, so I updated my iterm2 version (from build 1.0.0 to 1.0.0.201...), which magically reenabled the feature (perhaps the tab colors feature is only since this build? seems unlikely). Anyway, this helped me on the way to the solution and I don't have enough rep to upvote, so am marking as accepted solution.

Thanks!